# Bound quiver algebras over non algebraically closed fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

I am trying to learn some representation theory, mainly from the textbook *Elements of the representation theory of associative algebras* by Ibrahim Assem, Daniel Simson and Andrzej Skowronski. This textbook deals with algebras over algebraically closed fields. As far as I understand, one main reason for that is Theorem II.3.7 which states that a basic and connected finite dimensional algebra $A$ over an algebraically closed field is isomorphic to a bound quiver algebra. Using the fact that modules over a bound quiver algebra can be identified with representations of the bound quiver, one then can completely focus on studying representations of bound quivers for the purposes of this book.

However, and please correct me if I'm wrong, I don't see any reason that someone could not define a bound quiver algebra $K Q/I$ for a field $K$ which is not necessarily algebraically closed. In this way one gets many new algebras which are not covered by this textbook. Also, clearly Theorem II.3.7 does not hold anymore. But my question is, if one studies bound quiver algebras over a general field, at which point of the theory do the properties of the field come into play?

1. Is it still true that modules over $KQ/I$ and representations of $Q$ bound by $I$ can be identified?
2. If yes, can I still describe projective, injective and simple $KQ/I$-modules using the representations which are described in the algebraically closed case?
3. What about Auslander–Reiten theory? How much do the Auslander–Reiten translations and the Auslander–Reiten quiver depend on the field?

By looking at the proofs I am pretty certain that the answer to 1. is yes, I am not certain about the answer to 2. (because simple modules seem different for algebraically closed fields by Corollary I.3.2. to Schur's Lemma), and I would guess that the answer to 3. is that the Auslander–Reiten theory of $KQ/I$ depends heavily on the field.

I tried to search for a similar question but I didn't find any, sorry if this is a duplicate!

Comment: You can certainly look at bound quivers over any field.  Since the algebra of a bound quiver is split my guess is their representation theory doesn't change when you go to the algebraic closure but I could be wrong

Comment: The answer to your first two questions is yes

Comment: I think  that issue over arbitrary fields is that one loses the Morita equivalence between bound quiver algebras and arbitrary f.d algebras over some field k. The key point for me is that Wedderburns theorem gives not such a nice picture for A/J(A) for A an algebra over a non algebraically closed field (i.e. it does not have to be basic).